# Fastest way to get remaining count to next ceiling ten in C#

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I'm doing a operation in a very large set of numbers (13 digit length each).

I need to validate each number with checksum. Checksum digit will tell how far number is it to next ten, so i.e.:

```
checksum    checksum digit
      20                 0
      21                 9
      22                 8
      33                 7
      34                 6
      35                 5
      36                 4
      37                 3
     208                 2
       9                 1
```

The numbers are EAN-13 format. So, the maximum digits sum = 217 (999999999999: no checksum validation).

By far, the fastest way I have think is preloading data into a int array and retrieving it by index.

Is this the fastest way possible?

Or at this point this does not matter anymore, since it will be executed fast enough even to a lot of numbers?

## UPDATE:

preloading values of checksum digit for cheksum into an array as I mentioned:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 220; i += 10)
{
    matchValues[i] = 0;
    matchValues[i + 1] = 9;
    matchValues[i + 2] = 8;
    matchValues[i + 3] = 7;
    matchValues[i + 4] = 6;
    matchValues[i + 5] = 5;
    matchValues[i + 6] = 4;
    matchValues[i + 7] = 3;
    matchValues[i + 8] = 2;
    matchValues[i + 9] = 1;
}
```

With this I can cover all checksums with matching checksum digit `matchValues[sum];`

So:
matchValues[208] = 2;
matchValues[9] = 1;
etc.

Comment: Are the numbers stored in a file? If so, no need to preload them, just iterate over the file one number at a time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `By far, the fastest way I have think is preloading data into a int array and retrieving it by index.`. Are you checking the whole array to the next ceiling ten? How big are your datasets? Where do you get them from, a file, a database, etc.?

Comment: @ChrisK I1ve updated my question with mentioned preloading array. I'm generating all combinations of 13-length digits in memory (one-by-one for incrementing `long` var) to filter valid EAN-13 codes. I want to generate my own gps1 database from querying against others existent in the web with my EAN-13 codes.

Comment: So you want to create all possible 13 digit combinations and then filter out all invalid EAN-13 codes? But why don't you just create valid codes to begin with? Also, I think the networking part will most likely the least performant one...

Comment: yes. you're right it does no make any sense generate the 12 + checksum digit. i'm going to generate just for used prefixes (3-first digits) too.

Comment: I added some code below that will generate the EAN-13 check-digit for a given input with some decent speed. Also, I think the ` maximum digits sum = 217` is wrong. According to Wikipedia, every odd digit is multiplied by three.

Comment: For the greatest theoretical code 999999999999 (12 "9's"), checksum will be 216: 6*9*1 + 6*9*3 = 6*9*4 = 216.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use modulus for this. Your "cache" of values won't help much because the cost saved in the subtraction will be incurred in the lookup of the dictionary value by key, which in turn will call `GetHashCode()` and have some overhead:

```
int distanceFromNextTen = (10 - input % 10) % 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo to get the distance from the ceiling ten. You still would need to iterate over each number obviously.

```
int modulo = i % 10;
int distanceFromTen = modulo == 0 ? 0 : 10 - modulus;
```

Another solution would be `int distanceFromTen = (int)(Math.Ceiling(i / 10d) * 10 - i);`.

I've run benchmarks for both approaches:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("Checking {0}", i);

    int loops = 10;

    long averageModulo = 0;
    long averageCeiling = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < loops; l++)
    {

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            int modulus = i % 10;
            int distanceFromTen = modulus == 0 ? 0 : 10 - modulus;
        }
        sw.Stop();


        Stopwatch swTwo = new Stopwatch();

        swTwo.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        {
            int distanceFromTenTwo = (int)(Math.Ceiling(i / 10d) * 10 - i);
        }

        swTwo.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Modulo:       {0} ({1}ms)", sw.ElapsedTicks, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        averageModulo += sw.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine("Math.Ceiling: {0} ({1}ms)", swTwo.ElapsedTicks, swTwo.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        averageCeiling += swTwo.ElapsedTicks;

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Average modulo:  {0}", averageModulo / loops);
    Console.WriteLine("Average ceiling: {0}", averageCeiling / loops);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The modulo operation is always faster than the ceiling (might be because of the boxing). This being said, both operations are very fast.

---

With the new edit I think this is now aimed at generating valid EANs in as little time as possible. Here is some code that will generate 100000000 EAN-13 checksums (as documented on the Wikipedia page) in toughly 3.5 seconds.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");

        long start = 0;
        long end = 99999999;

        long count = end - start + 1;
        long[] eans = new long[count];

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();

        Parallel.For(start, end + 1, i => {
            eans[i] = GenerateEAN13(i);
        });

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Generation of {0} EAN-13s took {1} ticks ({2} ms)", count, sw.ElapsedTicks, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static long GenerateEAN13(long number)
    {
        long checksum = 0;
        long digit = 0;
        long tmp = number;

        for (int i = 13; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            digit = tmp % 10;
            tmp = tmp / 10;

            checksum += i % 2 == 0 ? digit * 3 : digit;

            if (tmp < 10)
                break;
        }

        long modulus = checksum % 10;
        checksum = modulus == 0 ? 0 : 10 - modulus;

        return number * 10 + checksum;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using your first expression.. but this is a issue in ending 0 numbers. they get 10 e not 0. So the extra If takes time.. :(

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed it. The extra if will most likely take so few time, it doesn't even matter.